# Difference between scrypt package and crypto module in Node?

Tags: node.js, scrypt

What is the difference between the [`scrypt` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrypt) on NPM and the [`scrypt` functions](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback) in the built-in `crypto` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scrypt package is deprecated while the [scrypt function](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback) is the recommended built-in

https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt

> #WARNING!!! This module is deprecated. Instead, use https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

The 'raw scrypt hash function' `scrypt.hash()` from [node-scrypt](https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt) is now available in the core Node.js [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback) module. For the `scrypt.kdf()` / `scrypt.verifyKdf()` functions, [scrypt-kdf](https://github.com/chrisveness/scrypt-kdf) is a close-to-direct replacement.